# Build multi columns as pivot in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying pivot the data based on existing data. I have details as below.

[image]

based on strt_dt, I need to do pivot up to 36 months. I cannot add 36 cols as pivoting by using min or max functions. Please advice me what is the better way. I need to pivot 36 cols for 36 months.
Like strt_dt value is 202003 then 202004,202005,202006....202305.

Table sample data:
[image]

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you build a dynamic query.
e.g. first build the columns :

```
select listagg('SUM(CASE WHEN to_char(start_dt,''YYYYMM'')=' 
                ||sdt||' THEN PRC_AMT END) as prc_amt'
                ||sdt,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sdt)
  into colList
  from (select distinct to_char(start_dt,'YYYYMM') sdt 
          from price_details)
```

then generate the actual query :

```
lv_sql := 'select '||colList||'
             from price_details
            group by to_char(start_dt,''YYYYMM'')';
```

and execute it any way you want :

```
execute immediate lv_sql into your_variables;
```